# using Mod_rewrite to redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I need to redirect from `http://test-glad/redirect` TO `https://test-glad/start.do`

The main problem being I need to maintain POST parameters in the request.

I am unable to do this using standard http redirection as POST params aren't resent as specified in the RFC

I have also tried using Proxy Pass which would not work.

I am now trying to do this using Apache URL rewriting but struggling. Do you know if this is possible. If so some help with the syntax would be much appreciated.

I am using Apache 2.2

Many Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 3):

are you trying it on localhost or on a live server?
Redirect http to https (SSL for entire website)
try this in .httaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=askapache:%2]

# redirect urls with index.html to folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index.html HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index.html$ http%{ENV:askapache}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# change // to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)//(.*) HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http%{ENV:askapache}://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is for a live server. Sorry I dont know where the .httaccess file is. I just have a httpd.conf file.

Comment: I have tried you first suggestion but it didnt have any effect. But I am not confident that the rule is being hit. I tried a basic redirect rule which also didnt work. I have loaded the mod-rewrite module. do i need to do anything else?

Comment: ok.. sorry its .htaccess file, if you don't have it, then create a new file name `.htaccess` {with a dot!} & put the code (try anyone, should work) in the file & place the file in the root of your server directory say if its public_html or www directory. & I'm sure mod_rewrite is enabled in httpf.conf file can be verified via phpinfo()

Comment: check this link if it helps
[link](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)

Comment: ok, I have got your first solution working. It was working from me as I had redirects in place using vitualhost port 80. The direct is now working but not passing though the post params.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get it, Do u mean that https redirect is working if you do not use port 80 & it doesn't if you use port 80? is that what you mean?
as you do have access to httpd.conf, check this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)

Comment: It was working previously because there were 301 redirect in place. I have now reverted to a clean conf file and added the code suggested. This worked after adding a minor tweak mentioned in your above link. I am now getting a 400 bad request error when adding [PT] to the end of the rule in an attempt to maintain POST params.

Comment: sorry not much idea on it, but check this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) for some configuration, hope it helps.