# This page isn’t working (redirected you too many times.)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hey i'm using ubuntu with apache2

after adding this htaccess code to redirect from http to https
i got this error msg.

This page isn’t working  (redirected you too many times.)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you have that on both HTTP and HTTPS versions?

Comment: tadman sloved ty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Mod\_rewrite to redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521647/using-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-http-to-https)